# In InDesign can a picture box object's effects (drop shadow) be copied to a different picture box?

Tags: adobe-indesign

When I select an object and apply a drop shadow from the effects menu, then select a different object the effects menu reverts to the default instead of the last settings. Is there a way to copy the last effect used or keep the last effect's settings? In Photoshop, you can copy layer styles to other layers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the old object that has the applied effect you want to copy, then go to **Window > Effects** to open the Effects panel. Drag the little "*fx*" icon next to the Object in the list onto your new object to apply the same effect to it.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to ask InDesign to remember the last effect instead of a default?

Comment: Not that I know of off-hand. If it's something you use often enough, you can make a new Object Style and then use that to change your default Object Style settings, but it's a little different than changing the default effects settings like Photoshop does. This link is a little old, I'm not sure if it's still accurate, but it might help: https://indesignsecrets.com/change-default-drop-shadow-settings.php

Answer (score 1):

If you create an object style, you can apply it to multiple objects in one go. If needed, other effects can be part of the same style. And you can assign a short-cut, which often comes in handy. Object styles often seem to be overlooked - I find them quite useful.